# Sench Touch: What is the Easiest Way to Prevent Multiple Taps on Ext.Button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I am developing a Sencha Touch game, but I have huge issue with multiple button taps by users.
I want a simple code/property to add in app.js so that even if a user taps a Button many times, or presses long time, Sencha Touch executes only 1 single tap event and not multiple events.

I have checked these links, but they did not help me:
https://gist.github.com/MrTomato8/36a764a19c91eacb6819

Comment: What about the `buffer` listener option?

Comment: You could disable the button once it is pressed.

Comment: Yes, I know about "disabling/enabling" of buttons but am looking for something much better

Comment: Buffer listener is not really stable since it is like a setTimeout. It can protect against ddouble tap but not multiple taps

Answer (score 0):

Inside release or tap event function for that button you can verify by below line of code.

```
if(self.getCls() == 'x-button-pressing')
  return;
```

because 'x-button-pressing' css class is added automatically by button component on pressing.